# Pairwise independence of arbitrary product of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have the following problem:

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ independent random variables such that, $\forall \ i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ :
$$ \mathbb{P}[X_i = 1] = \dfrac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}[X_i = -1] $$

Let $Y_S = \prod_{i\in S} X_i$ for every $\emptyset \neq S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Show that, if $T,S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\},\ T \neq S$, then $Y_T$ is independent of $Y_S$.

I've already show that, if $Z_m = \prod_{i=1}^{m} X_i$ then $Z_1, Z_2,\ldots , Z_n$ are independent, but with this more general statement I'm having trouble.

By a combinatorial argument, I've already found that $\mathbb{P}[Y_S = 1] = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}[Y_S = -1]$ for every $\emptyset \neq S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and then
$$\mathbb{P}[Y_S = y]\cdot\mathbb{P}[Y_T = y] = \left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 \qquad \mbox{for } y \in \{-1,1\}.$$

My problem comes when calculating the joint probability $\mathbb{P}[Y_T = y_T, Y_S = y_S]$.

In the case of the $Z_m$ variables, the calculation was quite simple since
$$\mathbb{P}[Z_1 = z_1, Z_2 = z_2,\ldots, Z_n = z_n] = \mathbb{P}\left[X_1 = z_1, X_2 = \frac{z_2}{z_1}, \ldots , X_n = \frac{z_n}{z_1\cdots z_{n-1}}\right]$$

and the proof follows by the independence of $X_i$. But in the general case, since it is not certain that one set is contained in the other (for example $S\subseteq T$ and even if one set was a subset of the other, I still don't see it as easy as the first proof), then I do not see how to express that probability in terms of the X_i and then apply the independence.

Any help trying to follow the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint. You need to calculate $4$ cases. Consider $Y_{T \cap S}$. Let $Y_{\emptyset} \equiv 1$. Then you'll have $\mathbb P(Y_T=1,Y_S=1) = \mathbb P(Y_T=1,Y_S=1,Y_{T \cap S}=1) + \mathbb P(Y_T=1,Y_S=1,Y_{T \cap S} = -1) = \mathbb P(Y_{T \setminus S}=1, Y_{S \setminus T} = 1, Y_{T \cap S}=1) + \mathbb P(Y_{T \setminus S}=-1, Y_{S \setminus T}=-1, Y_{T \cap S} = -1)$. Do you see how to finish and tackle other cases?

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks for the comment. Ok,I think I understand some things: so, we're applying total probability law conditioning to $Y_{T\cap S}$, and then I see $T\setminus S = T \setminus \{T\cap S\}$ and $S\setminus T = S \setminus \{T\cap S\}$ are disjoint. I know disjoint events do not imply independent events, but I wonder if I can apply it here.

Also, another question, why do we can consider $Y_{\emptyset} \equiv 1$? also, does that imply $\mathbb{P}[Y_{\emptyset} = -1] = 0$?

Comment: It is a matter of convention that $Y_{\emptyset} \equiv 1$. Note that in fact $Y_{\emptyset}$ makes no sense, but I've written $Y_{T \setminus S}$, where $T \setminus S$ might be empty. So we need to make sense of term $Y_{\emptyset}$ and it's $1$ because being $1$ does nothing to our terms. Note that for disjoint subsets $A,B$ you clearly have $Y_A,Y_B$ independent, since $X_1,...,X_n$ were independent and $Y_A,Y_B$ for disjoint $A,B$ depends on disjoint families $\{ X_j : j \in A\}$ and $\{X_i : i \in B\}$ so those are indeed independent.

Comment: @DominikKutek Ok, got it. And I can see the other 3 cases. One more question, in the first comment, we have $\mathbb{P}[Y_{T} = 1, Y_S = 1, Y_{T\cap S} = 1] + \mathbb{P}[Y_{T} = 1, Y_S = 1, Y_{T\cap S} = -1] = \mathbb{P}[Y_{T\setminus S} = 1, Y_{S\setminus T} = 1, Y_{T\cap S} = -1]  + \mathbb{P}[Y_{T\setminus S} = -1, Y_{S\setminus T} = -1, Y_{T\cap S} = -1] $. In the last term I think you meant $\mathbb{P}[Y_{T\setminus S} = 1, Y_{S\setminus T} = 1, Y_{T\cap S} = -1] $. If not, I don't understand what happened there.

Comment: In order to have $Y_{T}=1$ you must have both $Y_{T \cap S}, Y_{T \setminus S}$ have the same sign, because $Y_T = Y_{T \cap S} \cdot Y_{T \setminus S}$. Okay?

Comment: @DominikKutek You're right, I've totally missed that. I think I can finish the proof from here. I really appreciate your help.